# Get the Foreign Keys with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, innodb

I'm creating a class in PHP where I just have the parameter of the Table Name and fetch all the Columns and Values. But I don't know how get the values of the Columns with Foreign Keys.
 That's because I don't know to which table is related.

I need a way that I can *get the Foreign Key with PHP or SQL from a known table*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MySql, you can query the `information_schema` to get meta information about the database.

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME AS `table_name`,
  COLUMN_NAME AS `column_name`,
  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME AS `referenced_column_name`,
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME AS `referenced_table_name`
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
  AND REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
```

From: https://github.com/troelskn/pdoext/blob/master/lib/pdoext/connection.inc.php#L413 (Specifically the `loadKeys` function)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL command:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable
```